# Xcode error: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, photoeditorsdk

I am using the PhotoEditorSDK and I am getting an error in Xcode 9.0:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Users/.../PhotoEditorSDK.framework/PhotoEditorSDK
>   Reason: image not found

It showed up only when I updated the new Xcode, also I have tried all the stuff for clearing cache, derived data, setting the always embed swift libraries to true, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried to do `pod install` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the new version of the framework fixed the issue.